# Calendar.getInstance() returns NullPointerException in ios device?

Tags: java, time, calendar

When I try to get the current time I am using below code. But it shows `Null Pointer Exception` in Apple device. It is working fine in Android device.

How to solve this exception? What's  wrong in my code?

```
String hourValue    = "";
String minutesValue = "";
String amPm         = "AM";
Calendar now        = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour            = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute          = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int amPmVal         = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
if(hour > 12){
    hour = hour -12;
}
if(hour == 0){
    hour = 12;
}
if(amPmVal == 1){
    amPm = "PM";
}
hourValue = hour+"";
minutesValue    = minute+"";                
if(minute < 10){
     minutesValue = "0"+minutesValue;
}
return hourValue+":"+minutesValue+" "+amPm;
```

Comment: have you created an instance of calender somewhere else?, if there is no instance to reference, it will give you a nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1):

> `Calendar.getInstance()` returns `NullPointerException` in ios device?

No it doesn't.  And it doesn't return `null` either.

Here is you code.

```
Calendar now        = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour            = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

You obtained an instance of `Calendar` and assigned it to `now`.

Then you used the `Calendar` object that a different variable called `calendar` refers to.

Unless you have initialized the `calendar` variable somewhere else, the second statement will give you a NPE.

Solution: use the value of `now`!

> When I try to get the current time I am using below code. But it shows Null Pointer Exception in Apple device. It is working fine in Android device.

Presumably on the Android device you are initializing the `calendar` variable.

Comment: sorry, code mistake. if i placed correctly (i.e) 'now' variable placed. still i am getting the same Exception.

Comment: I'm afraid that I have no confidence that the code you have shown us (this time) corresponds to the code that you are actually running.

Comment: Also, which Java for IOS are you actually using here?

Comment: yes it shows NullPointerException.believe me. it's true

Comment: Oh I believe you that you get an NPE.  I just don't believe that you have shown us the real code.  I mean ... what was the stuff that you showed us first time?  How did those errors creep in if you copied the real code into the question?

Comment: i am using JDK 1.8 in my app.

Comment: Whose JDK 8? Where did you get it from?  (Last time I checked, Oracle doesn't ship Java for IOS, and neither does Apple.)

Comment: The problem here is that `Calendar.getInstance()` returns `null` and first call on `now.get(...)` throw nullpointer exception because now is null. Always check one line above and line below then analizing exceptions. I currently have the same problem specified here with SpringBoot + dynamically compiled and loaded java code's Calendar...

Comment: @Vinigas - please post a new question, and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows `Calendar.getInstance()` returning `null`.  Unfortunately, the OP for this question post all sorts of stuff that was unreliable ... and insufficient to allow a proper investigation.

Comment: For the record, I have examined the source code for `Calendar.getInstance` in Java 11.  The only way that `getInstance` can return null is if the JVM has been configured to use a `CalendarProvider` that is returning `null` instances.  My analysis is that none of the standard providers can do that.